# Retrieve the ManagementCertificate for a German Azure subscription (Frankfurt)

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure

I'm trying to get the **ManagementCertificate** for a subscription located in **Germany central** (Frankfurt). For a non-german Subscription, I can obtain the certificate using the old `manage.windowsazure.com` portal but unfortunately the old portal is not available for a subscription located in Germany central.

I already tried to retrieve the publishsettings file (which contains the ManagementCertificate) using the Azure PowerShell cmdlet. `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`:

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile -Environment AzureGermanCloud
```

This will open the web page https://manage.microsoftazure.de/publishsettings/index But the site is not available...

How do I retrieve the ManagementCertificate for a subscription located in Germany central?

Comment: Are you able to access the management portal for Azure Germany?

Comment: @GauravMantri Only the new portal, the signup within the old classic portal doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is **not yet supported**. However, I sent the certificate to a microsoft employee who could upload the certificate.